# Where are functions like "_M_construct" defined

Tags: c++, stl

I disassembled a very simple C++ program written by myself on Debian. It involves a few `std::string` operations. In the disassembly code, I can see many references to something like below:

```
<void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag)>
```

I believe this is the concrete string constructor created by some templates function to initialize my string. However, the disassembled code does not seem to provide a clue on where exactly the templates function is defined.

I checked `/usr/include/c++/10/string`, I can't find much here.
I also asked ChatGPT, it says that it is defined in `libstdc++-10-dev`, I issued `apt-get source libstdc++-10-dev` to get the source as advised by it, but I only find stuff like below, which isn't really what I am looking for (For example, in `debian/libcc1-0.symbols`, I can see four lines, only those strings, but no function body):

```
18 results - 4 files

debian/libcc1-0.symbols:
   8   (optional=abi_c++17)_ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJS5_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS5_S7_EEDpOT_@Base 8
   9:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag@Base 8
  10:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag@Base 8
  11   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EED1Ev@Base 10

debian/libstdc++6.symbols.32bit.cxx11:
  116   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE11_M_capacityEj@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  117:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructEjc@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  118   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13_M_set_lengthEj@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  119   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE14_M_replace_auxEjjjc@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  120:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE18_M_construct_aux_2Ejc@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  121   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE2atEj@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2

  170   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE11_M_capacityEj@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  171:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE12_M_constructEjw@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  172   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE13_M_set_lengthEj@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  173   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE14_M_replace_auxEjjjw@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  174:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE18_M_construct_aux_2Ejw@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  175   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE2atEj@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2

debian/libstdc++6.symbols.64bit.cxx11:
  116   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE11_M_capacityEm@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  117:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructEmc@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  118   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13_M_set_lengthEm@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  119   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE14_M_replace_auxEmmmc@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  120:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE18_M_construct_aux_2Emc@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  121   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE2atEm@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2

  170   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE11_M_capacityEm@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  171:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE12_M_constructEmw@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  172   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE13_M_set_lengthEm@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  173   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE14_M_replace_auxEmmmw@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  174:  (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE18_M_construct_aux_2Emw@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
  175   (optional=abi_c++11)_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE2atEm@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 5.2
```

So the questions are:

1. Do functions with name like `:_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag)` really exist?
2. If so, where can I find them?
3. If not, how can I know which templates generates it?

Comment: Bing tells me it is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/libstdc++/api/a01004_source.html), `template<class _Tp> class polymorphic_allocator`

Comment: @KenY-N Lol, you mean the old Bing or the new Bing. The link isn't exactly the place but it does point the correct direction, i.e., it is in the gcc's repo. I believe the correct file is [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/libstdc++/api/a00293_source.html), I can find an exact match of the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I am a bit late, I will try to answer your question anyway.

The helper function you have shown is a specialization of the following function, declared in the `basic_string.h` file:

```cpp
// For forward_iterators up to random_access_iterators, used for
// string::iterator, _CharT*, etc.
template<typename _FwdIterator>
  _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
  void
  _M_construct(_FwdIterator __beg, _FwdIterator __end,
std::forward_iterator_tag);
```

Its implementation can be found in the `basic_string.tcc` file:

```cpp
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
     template<typename _InIterator>
       _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
       void
       basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> ::
       _M_construct(_InIterator __beg, _InIterator __end,
std::forward_iterator_tag)
         {
           size_type __dnew = static_cast<size_type>(std::distance(__beg, __end));

           if (__dnew > size_type(_S_local_capacity))
             {
                _M_data(_M_create(__dnew, size_type(0)));
                _M_capacity(__dnew);
             }
           else
                _M_use_local_data();

           // Check for out_of_range and length_error exceptions.
           struct _Guard
             {
               _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
               explicit _Guard(basic_string* __s) : _M_guarded(__s) { }

               _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
               ~_Guard() { if (_M_guarded) _M_guarded->_M_dispose(); }

               basic_string* _M_guarded;
             } __guard(this);

           this->_S_copy_chars(_M_data(), __beg, __end);

           __guard._M_guarded = 0;

           _M_set_length(__dnew);
         }
```

Comment: Hi @LoS, yes it is a bit late indeed, in my 2nd comment (Mar 22 at 6:12), I find it out based on the first comment by Ken. But hopefully your answer can help other developers in the future!